# Slide in hamburger menu adds horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

The result should be a hamburger menu with slides in from the right on clicking the icon.

This is the code for the main menu where I translate it to the right 100% and when I click on the icon it translates back to 0% bringing it on screen

HTML

```
<div id="mobilenav" class="mobile-nav">
  <div class="mobile-nav-header">
    
    </div>
    <div class="hamburger">
      <button (click)="closeMenu()">
        <img src="../../assets/icons/close-menu.svg" alt="" />
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="links">
    
  </ul>
  <div class="socials">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.mobile-nav {
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  right: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background: white;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

The JS

```
openMenu() {
    var mobile_menu = document.getElementById('mobilenav');
    mobile_menu!.style.transform = 'translateY(0px)';
    // mobile_menu!.style.display = 'block';
  }
  closeMenu() {
    var mobile_menu = document.getElementById('mobilenav');
    mobile_menu!.style.transform = 'translateX(100%)';
    // mobile_menu!.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

The issue is that when closed, it is still possible for the user to scroll horizontally to the right. That should not be possible as the menu should be hidden and there should be no possibility to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Then you need to remove the overflow of the element where the user can scroll. Moving it out of the window doesn't mean it doesn't exist anymore. I would suggest here to toggle a class on body element and then handle all this with CSS.

Comment: Can you also show us the Html?

Comment: @AlanMeile Added HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to replace `position: absolute` with `position: fixed`. This fixes the problem but still allows the page to be horizontally scrollable if needed.

Alternatively, you could add

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

to remove the horizontal scrollbar.